# При изменении переменных ничего не меняется

Tags: java

При выборе года, проверка на високосность совершается но все значения выстраиваются по умолчанию первому введенному, далее при их изменении, ничего не меняется, я как понимаю надо сделать что то чтобы при изменении процесс начинался и просчитывался заново, как это называется.

Подскажите может есть видеокурс хороший по джава, чувствую плваю.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public int maxDay = 31;
public int maxYear = 2016;
public int minYear = 1940;
public int maxMonth = 12;
public int minMonth = 1;
public int minDay = 1;
public int yearChoseInt;
public int monthChoseInt = 0;
public int modif = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    NumberPicker numberPicker3 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker3);
    numberPicker3.setMaxValue(maxYear);
    numberPicker3.setMinValue(minYear);
    yearChoseInt = numberPicker3.getValue();//получаем значение года
    // yearChoose = (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.numberPicker3);

    if(yearChoseInt%4==0 && yearChoseInt%100 !=0 || yearChoseInt%400==0){   //проверка високосности года
        modif = modif+1;
    }
    else {
        modif = 0;
    }

    NumberPicker numberPicker2 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker2);
    numberPicker2.setMaxValue(maxMonth);
    numberPicker2.setMinValue(minMonth);
    monthChoseInt = numberPicker2.getValue();//получаем значение месяца

    // monthChoose = (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.numberPicker2);

    monthChoseInt = numberPicker2.getValue();//получаем значение месяца

    switch (yearChoseInt)
    {
        case 1:
        case 3:
        case 5:
        case 7:
        case 8:
        case 10:
        case 12:
            maxDay = 31;
            break;
        case 4:
        case 6:
        case 9:
        case 11:
            maxDay = 30;
            break;
        case 2:
        default:
            maxDay = 28 + modif;
    }

    NumberPicker numberPicker = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
    numberPicker.setMaxValue(maxDay);
    numberPicker.setMinValue(minDay);


}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понял, весь код выполняется в методе onCreate, этот метод выполняется при создании данной активности только один раз. Чтобы при изменении введенного числа функция срабатывала снова, следует сделать кнопку, либо обработать сигнал изменения данных в поле ввода, и код вычисления года вынести в метод, отвечающий за нажатие кнопки/изменение данных в поле ввода.

О том, как реализовать метод, реагирующий на изменение значения:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15983120/implementing-onvaluechange-to-a-numberpicker-in-android и обработку года поместить внутрь.

Документация андроида о NumberPicker:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html

Comment: получается что то вроде этого

Comment: monthChoose.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
                oldVal = minMonth;
                newVal = monthChoseInt;
                switch (monthChoseInt)
             .....
  }

Comment: Не только свич туда, но и getValue. И если год и месяц берутся из разных полей, то для поля года тоже следует сделать метод, который будет устанавливать новое значение yearChoseInt, а саму эту переменную сделать свойством класса либо как-то передавать в функцию проверки месяца

Comment: И еще у вас там наоборот присваивание: `oldVal = minMonth; newVal = monthChoseInt` а надо наоборот: `minMonth = oldVal; monthChoseInt = newVal`, так как значения oldVal и newVal передаются в ваш метод из поля

Comment: а если же надо установить новые, то это делается через методы setMin/MaxValue

Comment: маленько разобрался спасибо, вставил два override , даже стало обновляться... но печем-то после обновления года не обновляются месяцы , где то что то не туда перенес, пока разбираюсь

Comment: Просто поле года обновляет только переменную года, но не месяцы. Их можно как-то связать, например при изменении года посылать сигнал, или установку месяца вынести в отдельный метод и вызывать его и при изменении года и при изменении месяца